# How do I set rotation on the Gamekit login banner in an iOS game?

Tags: ios, gamekit

I'm working on an iOS game that supports multiple orientations. For most Game Kit views, it's easy to support rotation; you can grab the view property off of the appropriate view controller and apply the proper transform when you show the screen.

However, I've found no way to do this with the Game Center banners that pop up asynchronously, like the "welcome back" popup that happens after successful login. That's got no view controller I can find since it's shown by the runtime independent of my code.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: make sure you have a root view controller attached to the top level window, and that view controller is properly responding to orientation changes, even if you're doing the rest in GL...